# CSS Fontawesome Icon Click able in IE 10

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, font-awesome

**I had added Fontawesome Icon in css to display it in select Dropdown 
Now I am not able to click the Fontawesome Icon in IE 10 can any one know how to solve this**

HTML

```
<div class="select">
  <select>
    <option value="">Order By</option>
    <option value="1">ID</option>
    <option value="2">Details</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.select {
  position: relative
}

.select select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  border: 0;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.select select::-ms-expand {
  display: none;
}

.select:after {
  content: '\f0d7';
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  top: 6px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wrx0btg9/1/)**

Comment: Show some code that you tried.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wrx0btg9/1/

Comment: unable to add that in the subject

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the `icons` beside your existing elements in the dropdown, you have to include that you want them next to your *HTML* elements. Meaning, you have to add the specific *FontAwesome* `icon` next to your dropdown element for it to display. If that was your question.

Like this; `<option value=""><i class="fa fa-your-content"></option>`.

Else it won't display no matter how hard you try.

---

Additionally, have you linked to the *FontAwesome* source or *CDN*? Because without the source code, you can't display any of the customized elements.

Comment: I am able to display the icon but not able to click that icon in IE

Comment: I can't see where the icon is located, could you provide a screenshot?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wrx0btg9/1/ in this link @ the select the down arrow is fontawesome icon

Comment: Do you mean to change the cursor on hover?